# What is the best way to reference and call info in a naming db

Tags: php, mysqli, computer-science

I have two db's. One holds all the created time codes with an exclusive id# (`code_id`) to the time code. it looks like this:

```
----------------------------------------------
|                  time_codes                |
----------------------------------------------
|code_id | dept_id | code_number | code name |
----------------------------------------------
|   10   |    9    |    13       | Excavation|
|   11   |    9    |     4       | Concrete  |
|   12   |   11    |    73       | Masonry   |
----------------------------------------------
```

Then I have entered time sheet records db, Where an employee has recorded his time on each task for the day. It looks like this:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------
|                            time_log                         |
---------------------------------------------------------------  
| id | date | job_number | department_id | code_id | log_time |
---------------------------------------------------------------
| 59 | y-m-d| xx-xx-xxxx |       9       |    13   |    3.25  |
| 64 | y-m-d| xx-xx-xxxx |      11       |    73   |    6.00  |
---------------------------------------------------------------
```

I want to reference the `code_number,code_name` when recalling entries on the recorded `time_log`. I want to know what the best method is to reference them efficiently without taxing the server.

I have thought of two methods;
1. In the while() loop that is pulling each `time_log` record i could make a mysqli_query to look up the `code_id` and then grab the name and print it in the designated spot.
which would look something like this:

```
$hours_qry = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT `date`,`job_number`,`code_id`,`log_time` FROM `time_log` WHERE `date` BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('$from_date', '%Y-%m-%d') AND STR_TO_DATE('$to_date', '%Y-%m-%d') ORDER BY `date` ASC, `job_number` DESC,`code_id` ASC");
    // get records within work week
    while($result = mysqli_fetch_array($hours_qry)){
       $Cdate = $result['date'];
       $Cjob_number = $result['job_number'];
       $Ccode_id = $result['code_id'];
       $Clog_time = $result['log_time'];

       // get code name and number for display
       $code_qry = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT `code_number`,`code_name` from `time_codes` WHERE `code_id` = $Ccode_id");
       while($code_results = mysqli_fetch_array($code_qry)){
          $code_number = $code_results['code_number'];
          $code_name = $code_results['code_name'];
       }

    }
```

However i think this would create unnecessary query calls over and over each time the loop is processing an entry.

So then  I thought maybe I could (but i don't know how to);
2. Make this `time_codes` query call before the `time_log` while() loop and make an array of the `time_codes`. then in the while() loop i could reference the array somehow and pull out the `code_number, code_name` that matches `code_id`.

Which is better, Or are both of these inferior to a more common method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is faster if you do the JOIN in the DB with one query rather than extracting by in 2 steps:

```
$query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT date, job_number, tl.code_id, log_time, code_number, code_name FROM time_codes tc JOIN time_log tl ON tc.code_id = tl.code_id WHERE date BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('$from_date', '%Y-%m-%d') AND STR_TO_DATE('$to_date', '%Y-%m-%d') ORDER BY date ASC, job_number DESC,tl.code_id ASC");

while($result = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
       $Cdate = $result['date'];
       $Cjob_number = $result['job_number'];
       $Ccode_id = $result['code_id'];
       $Clog_time = $result['log_time'];
       $code_number = $result['code_number'];
       $code_name = $result['code_name'];
}
```

Comment: oh i like this idea! But I can't get this to work. should it be more like this?
`$hours_qry = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT ``date``,``job_number``,``code_id``,``log_time``,``time_codes``.``code_number``,``time_codes``.``code_name`` FROM ``time_log`` JOIN ``time_codes`` ON ``time_log``.``code_id`` = ``time_codes``.``code_id`` WHERE ``date`` BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('$from_date', '%Y-%m-%d') AND STR_TO_DATE('$to_date', '%Y-%m-%d') ORDER BY ``date`` ASC, ``job_number`` DESC,``code_id`` ASC");

Comment: It's throwing you an error? If you are saying it doesn't work because it not showing anything that could be because `time_codes.code_id` does not match with any `time_log.code_id` in your example, but `time_codes.code_number` does indeed match with `time_log.code_id`. For me with your example works substituting `tc.code_id` for `tc.code_number`, but since you had it like the other way in your code I thought you have more data that match.

Comment: OH I got it to work with my query like this (fo ranyone following after to read this) `"SELECT date,job_number,time_log.code_id,log_time,time_codes.code_number,time_codes.code_name FROM time_log JOIN time_codes ON time_log.code_id = time_codes.code_id WHERE date BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('$from_date', '%Y-%m-%d') AND STR_TO_DATE('$to_date', '%Y-%m-%d') ORDER BY date ASC, job_number DESC,code_id ASC"`

Comment: Perfect! This "join" feature opens up a lot i can do with my code. Thank you @jordan Cortes